# What are some good Module Development Solution/Environments/Best Practices for Dot Net Nuke Modules

Tags: deployment, dotnetnuke, collaboration, dotnetnuke-module

I've been developing modules for DNN since version 2 and back then I was able to easily able to run my module as I developed it on my environment and still easily deploy my module as a DLL.
When version 4 came out and used the web site solution (rather than the Web Application solution).  It seems like there was something lost.  I can continue to develop in my test environment and immediately see changes as I make them, but releasing for me has become a headache.

I mostly do my development for one site in particular have just been using FTP deployment of the modules to the main site after I was done making changes.

I'd like to set up a good environment for multiple developers to be able to work on the module(s).

When adding stuff to source control, are people generally putting all of DNN into source control so they can bring the whole solution down to work on, or just their module and each person needs to set up their own dev DNN environment?

I'd like to start getting my modules projects organized so more people could work on them and I feel a bit lost for some best practices both in doing this and deploying those changes to a live site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a few detailed blog postings about this on my blog site, [mitchelsellers.com](http://www.mitchelsellers.com).

I personally use the WAP development model and I do NOT check the DNN solution, or any core files into source control, as I do NOT modify the core for any of my clients.  When working with multiple people we create a similar environment for each person, and still can work with each of our individual projects, at times we will have completely isolated dev environments with individual databases and code, at other times I have worked with a shared dev database to resolve issues with dev module installation issues.

With the WAP model I use a method to dynamically create my installation packages on project build using a post-build event and then I have a test installation that I use to validate that the packages occur.  Debugging is then done via Attach to Process.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest Mitchel book if you are needing some reference material - Professional Dotnetnuke Module Programming by Wrox [Module Programming - Michel Sellers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470171162)